# Dividing array gather row by row from SQL

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting name of company ID and employee that works for this company I would like to divide it into 2D array with `("name of company", array(employees))`

[image]

Right now I'm getting names of companies properly but I cannot seem to get employees correctly so corresponding employees set to proper companies.

```
  $officers = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        array_push($officers,$row['Officer_Name']); 
        if(!valueExists($DB, 'name', $row['Company_Name'])){ //Get rid of duplicates
            array_push($DB, array("name"=>$row['Company_Name'], "officers"=>$officers));
            $officers=array();


        }
    }

function valueExists($array, $key, $value){
    foreach($array as $item){
        if($item[$key]==$value){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```